# Golang возврат константной ссылки

Tags: golang

Как в `go` вернуть из функции ссылку на объект с запретом его изменять?

На плюсах я бы это написал примерно так:

```
A a;

A const * getA()
{
    return &a;
}
```

Хочу получить переменную, которой можно пользоваться в любом файле/пакете, получая ее указатель через специальный метод, но при этом чтобы ее нельзя было случайно изменить (чтобы любое изменение шло через отдельный метод, в котором будут проверки на корректность, логгирование и прочее). Как такое сделать в `go`?

Answer (score 1):

Для инкапсуляции объекта следует сделать его структурой:

```
type Counter struct { n int } // Поле структуры, имя которого начинается со строчной буквы, недоступно для клиентов из других пакетов
func (c *Counter) N() int { return c.n }
func (c *Counter) Increment() { c.n++ }
func (c *Counter) Reset() { c.n = 0 }
```

Теперь из других пакетов можно создавать экземпляр Counter, который предоставляет методы для получения значения, инкрементирования и сброса значения в ноль. Произвольно изменить значение будет нельзя.

Comment: А если задача вернуть указатель на структуру с множеством полей (конфиг грубо говоря), чтобы его при этом нельзя было случайно изменить, но без написания кучи инкапсулирующих методов для каждого поля?